# How to make UIPickerView not to display if delegate data is empty on textfield touch?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, uipickerview

I do not want to display UIPickerView if statusArray is empty when user touch up inside the text field for start editing. My requirement is after entering 3 characters, I'm going to make a web service call. In main app, I received all the response data & display on UIPickerView. Please suggest me how to hide UIPickerView till I received response from server.

[image]

Here is my sample code (web service call not included)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var statusText: UITextField!

let statusArray  = [String]()
let picker = UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    picker.dataSource = self
    picker.delegate = self


    //binding textfield to picker view
    statusText.inputView = picker


}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return statusArray.count
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return statusArray[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    statusText.text = statusArray[row]
}
```

}

//callback method from web service

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {

for location in locationDetails.ianaLocationInfoArray
{


    let optionToView = location.ianaCode! + " - " + location.facilityName!
    self.locationArray.append(optionToView)
    self.picker.reloadAllComponents()





}
     applicationUtils.hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)
}
```

Comment: is there any callback method for api calling?

Comment: Yes, Please check my code above.

Comment: then you show show the picker view in callback method and always hide

Comment: @SaurabhJain, I tried adding this code in web service callback call but it didn't open anything.  //binding textfield to picker view
                                            self.txtLocationCode.inputView = self.picker

Comment: Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// set inputView later if condition meets
// txtLocationCode.inputView = picker

// In callback method from web service, change the input type
// to picker instead of keyboard if condition meets

if(self.locationArray.count>0) {

    // below 3 lines are to set inputview as picker and to see picker immediately
    self.txtLocationCode.inputView = self.picker
    self.txtLocationCode.resignFirstResponder()
    self.txtLocationCode.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: picker.isHidden = true/false not working in code. I tried lots of time to hide my UIPickerView even in viewDidLoad method without any condition still it's  not hiding this element.

Comment: Currently your picker only shows when you tap on statusText?

Comment: Can you please check if picker is nil? Also please check [link](http://prntscr.com/g97t5b)

Comment: Yes, It's display all the time. I want to open it after entering  3 characters. so my web service can complete the request and prepare UIPickerView data ready for me.

Comment: Try changing the frame to confirm you have reference to picker or check if picker is nil?

Comment: Should I post my original code? I have not placed UIPickerView from object library, I have created object manually like let picker = UIPickerView(). So there is no changes for nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152065/discussion-between-hooda-and-michaeln-peterson).

Comment: Thank you very much for putting great affords to resolve my issue. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make if like this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
if statusArray.count == 0 {
    picker.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: It's not working. It's still showing me picker view. I have tried .isHidden as well as .alpha but no luck.

Comment: @michaelnpeterson, where is code that append picker to view?

Comment: statusText.inputView = picker

Comment: @michaelnpeterson, you can wrap line with delegate in if written above

Answer (score 0):

In webservice response :

```
if statusArray.count > 0{
  statusText.inputView = picker
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check `statusArray.count` in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
if statusArray.count == 0 {
    picker.isHidden = true
}
```

After inserting 3 characters make request with server for get data.**(As per you said.)** 
And check below condition ...

```
if statusArray.count > 0 {
    picker.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write and call the function in pickerview extension any where and will reset to picker view to the first row

```
extension UIPickerView {

    func reloadPicker(_ animated : Bool){
        print("\n\n Extension Is Calling \n\n")
        self.reloadAllComponents()
        self.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: animated)
    }
}
```